# Convert derived class object to base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, type-conversion

How can I convert an instance of derived class object to base class object?

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}

class DerrivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; } 
}
```

If I have objDerivedClass with 2 properties (MyProperty1, MyProperty2) how can I convert it to objBaseClass, to have an instance of base class object?

Comment: *Why???* You already have an instance of `BaseClass` by virtue of having a `DerrivedClass`. Why do you need to remove the `DerrivedClass` bits?

Comment: why would you want to 'step down'?

Comment: You just have to cast it: `(BaseClass)objDerivedClass`

Comment: i'm using entity framework and the base class is part of the model. but i get an instance of derived class from UI controls and i want to convert it to base class object.

Comment: using cast gives me derived class instance but without its properites

Comment: That's what we call it as `Polymorphism` and What you are asking can't be done as @BradleyDotNET rightly pointed.

Comment: Do you really want to _convert_? Or are you just in a situation where you have to pass an object of `BaseClass` to something? If the latter, then you don't need to do _anything_. You can always pass an instance of `DerivedClass` to something that wants a `BaseClass`, or assign a reference to a `DerivedClass` instance to a variable of type `BaseClass`.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET for me, I need to serve JSON objects, and i need to set an `Editable` field based on the `DbSet`'s ApprovedById field, but i don't want to expose the Id to the end user. I know i could use AutoMapper, but that's two arrays on the heap, plus, i would rather not stress the db with more fields than i need. It'd be nice to have a derived class that includes the ApprovedById field and then before i put it into JSON, i could just lop off the `ApprovedById` so the user could not see it. (Ids are completely opaque to the user. Could be a GUID, could be an `'int`, who knows?)

Comment: @MichaelTranchida There's the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute for that. Still doesn't invalidate that "changing" a derived class into it's base goes against how OOP has always worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really do that, and in general that goes against the point of inheriting classes - they have public and protected properties and methods of their base classes, plus everything you added to extend the functionality of the base. Casting a derived class to its base just throws away all the extra goodness you went to the trouble of adding.

If what you're asking is how to accept both BaseClass and the DerivedClass into any method or property, you can just have either ask for BaseClass - anything that accepts BaseClass will also accept DerivedClass, given that DerivedClass is considered an instance of BaseClass.

Comment: Thank you @furkle . ok then I guess, I need to rethink about my design.

Comment: @PeterDuniho b.GetType() returns "ChildFoo", and c.GetType() returns "Foo". Is there something important I'm missing here? Plus, c.GetType() != typeof(ChildFoo).

Comment: @peterduniho Oh, man, that's the worst place for a typo. The original code had (Foo)((object)b); Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right - I was bending over backwards to try to find a way of doing the silly thing the OP asked for, and ended up accomplishing nothing at all. Upon fixing the typo in the variables I found that, yes, the compiler still recognized the (Foo)((object)) cast as the child class. I've removed the example entirely.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've removed that as well. I'm not exactly sure why, but I was getting an InvalidCastException earlier. Obviously I wasn't doing (Foo)childFoo, but it's what I was intending to do, and it was causing an InvalidCastException. I'm cognizant of the fact that a ChildFoo will be accepted by anything that accepts a Foo, and I'd tried to get that across in my post. Again, thanks for the knuckle-raps - teaches me a valuable lesson about me trying to figure out new ways to make old mistakes. Feel free to let me know if there's anything else objectionable/incorrect.

Comment: @furkle: Nope, I'm out of steam...can't find anything else to whine about. :) Now that things are cleaned up and our conversation in the comments probably won't make much sense to anyone else, I'm going to go back and delete my side of it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well, regardless of whether it makes sense to any future onlookers, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: For me, I need to serve JSON objects, and i need to set an `Editable` field based on the `DbSet`'s ApprovedById field, but i don't want to expose the Id to the end user. I know i could use AutoMapper, but that's two arrays on the heap, plus, i would rather not stress the db with more fields than i need. It'd be nice to have a derived class that includes the ApprovedById field and then before i put it into JSON, i could just lop off the `ApprovedById` so the user could not see it. (Ids are completely opaque to the user. Could be a GUID, could be an `'int`, who knows?)